# When do $H_1 \cong H_2$ and $K_1 \cong K_2$ imply $F(H_1,K_1) \cong F(H_2,K_2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Suppose $H_1$ and $K_1$ are subgroups of $G_1$ and $H_2$ and $K_2$ are subgroups of $G_2$ such that $H_1 \cong H_2$ and $K_1 \cong K_2$.

When can we say $H_1 \cap K_1 \cong H_2 \cap K_2$?

If this holds and if those subgroups are normal, can we conclude $H_1K_1 \cong H_2K_2$? I also would like to know when this isomorphism holds.

Finally, if $H_1 \lhd K_1$ and $H_2 \lhd K_2$, do we have conditions to gurantee $K_1/H_1 \cong K_2/H_2?$

### Edit

My motivation to ask this question comes from the fact that if $I$ and $J$ are ideals of a ring then $$(I+J)/(I\cap J) \cong (I+J)/I\ \oplus (I+J)/J$$ Also, $I/(I\cap J) \cong (I+J)/J$ and $J/(I\cap J) \cong (I+J)/I$

Comment: None of these need to hold. A heavy-handed condition that guarantees them is that the isomorphisms be induced by a single automorphism of your over-arching group. This is sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: The isomorphisms you mention in your edit: second one is just the Isomorphism Theorems. First one is an application of the First Isomorphism Theorem. I do not see how any of them are related to the question you ask, though...

Comment: For counter-examples, you can consider 1) subspaces of a vector space 2) subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ of the form $m\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I consider $I/(I\cap J) =H_1$,$ H_2=(I+J)/J$, $K_1=J/(I\cap J)$, and $K_2=(I+J)/I$. Then I wondered $H_1+K_1 \cong H_2+K_2$.

Comment: The isomorphism comes from mapping $I+J$ to $(I+J)/I\oplus (I+J)/J$ and noting the kernel is the intersection, not from the second set of isomorphisms...

Comment: Thank you, I made a silly mistake. Do you have a counterexample for my second question? That is, $H_i \cong K_i$ and $H_1 \cap K_1 \cong H_2 \cap K_2$, but $H_1K_1 \cong H_2K_2$ fails. If $H_i \cap K_i$ are trivial, then $H_1K_1 \cong H_1 \times K_1 \cong H_2 \times K_2 \cong H_2 K_2$. Is it okay to ask this question in the comment, or is it better to ask it in a new question?